# How to use GetOptions in hash array?

Tags: perl

I used to 'GetOptions' in hash arrays.

I have a hash data structure below.

```
%fruit=(
    banana => [ 1, "yellow" ],
    cherry => [ 2, "dark red" ],
    strawberry => [ 3, "red" ],
);
```

The key is name of fruits.

Then I want to use 'GetOptions' for fruit 'name', 'number' and 'color'.

Can you please let me know how to use GetOptions...?

I want to use like -n for searching name and -i for number and -c for color.

Please let me know... :(

Comment: `GetOptions` is for processing command line options. What, Exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to use getoptions for name , number and color searches. For example type '-n' with name like 'banana' in command line, then searchinng banana=>[1, "yellow"]...

Comment: @user712390: That's not what you're asking in your question. If you want to be able to parse, "-n 1" or "-c red" as command line inputs, you're using GetOptions in a very simple way. See [GetOptions](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html). Restate your question with exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: sample command lines and output would make the question much clearer

Comment: Excuse my mini-rant, but why is it that people making a living programming don't know to specify sample input and desired output states? 1) What would the command line look like, 2) what do you want to do with the input?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're quite understanding what `GetOptions` does.

It parses the options you passed in.

So for your example:

```
> myprog.pl --name banana
```

In your program you would have:

```
my $name;
GetOptions("name=s" => \$name);
```

Your `$name` will then contain `banana`

You would then need to get the name from that variable, extract the matching entry from your `%fruit` hash, and output the results.

Answer (score 1):

`%fruit` is a hash, but the values in the hash are REFERENCES to a two member array.

What GetOptions does is take an array (such as `%ARGV)` and parses the options out of that array. You can put those options into scalars, arrays, and even hashes, but There's no direct way of saying that a command line option is a reference to an array.

The best you're going to be able to do is create an array that will contain that values:

```
$ myprogram --fruit banana=yellow --fruit cherry="dark red" --fruit strawberry=red
```

Then you can have:

```
 GetOptions('fruit=s' => \@fruitHash);
```

The array will look like this:

```
$fruit[0] = 'banana=yellow';
$fruit[1] = 'cherry=dark red';
$fruit[2] = 'strawberry=red';
```

From there, you could go through the array and create your hash reference:

```
my %fruitHash;
my $count = 1;
foreach my $value (@fruit) {
    my ($fruit, $color) = split(/=/, $value);
    $fruit{$fruit}=>[0] = $count,
    $fruit{$fruit)=>[1] = $color,
}
```

There's no way to get GetOptions to understand that the command line options are a reference to a two member array.

Answer (score 1):

You did no accept an answer. So may be this one fits.

Because you did not provide examples how to call your script, I assume something like this:

```
test.pl -i 3
```

gives us

```
strawberry, 3, red
```

and

```
test.pl -n cherry
```

gives us

```
cherry, 2, dark red
```

and

```
test.pl - c yellow
```

gives us

```
banana, 1, yellow
```

Use the following script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Std;
use vars qw (%opt);

getopts( "i:n:c:", \%opt ) or usage();

use Data::Dumper;
my %fruit=(
    banana => [ 1, "yellow" ],
    cherry => [ 2, "dark red" ],
    strawberry => [ 3, "red" ],
);

if ($opt{n}) {
   print "Fruit: $opt{n}, $fruit{$opt{n}}[0], $fruit{$opt{n}}[1] \n";
} elsif ($opt{i}) {
   while( my ($key, $value) = each %fruit) {
      if ($opt{i} == $value->[0] ) {
         print "Fruit: $key, $value->[0], $value->[1] \n";
         last;
      }
   }
} elsif ($opt{c}) {
   while( my ($key, $value) = each %fruit) {
      if ($opt{c} eq $value->[1] ) {
         print "Fruit: $key, $value->[0], $value->[1] \n";
         last;
      }
   }
}
```

If that is not what you need, tell us more!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to use getoptions for name , number and color searches. For example type '-n' with name like 'banana' in command line, then searchinng banana=>[1, "yellow"]

That's not your question. This is quite simple:

```
use GetOpt::Long;


my ($number, $name, $color);
my $results = GetOptions (
    "number=i" => \$number,
    "name=s"   => \$name,
    "color=s"  => \$color,
);
```

Then, check the values of $number, $name, and $color. (Also check $results and give a nice error message if GetOptions returns a `false` value);

```
my $numOfParams = 0;
if ($color)  {$numOfParams++};
if ($number) {$numOfParams++};
if ($name)   {$numOfParams++};

die qq(Too many options given\n) if ($numOfParams > 1);
die qq(You didn't give any parameters\n) #'
    if ($NumOfParams == 0);

if ($color) {
    searchOnColor($color);
} elsif ($number) {
    searchOnNumber($number);
} elsif ($name) {
    searchOnName($name);
}
```